# Sending Part of a Number to MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql

I haven't been able to find anything on this. I am taking credit card numbers from customers. The actual card number is being sent via API to Authorize.net, but I want to store the last 4 numbers of the card in mysql database. I just need to know how to take the last 4 numbers of this variable and set it to another variable to send to the database.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks everyone.

Comment: In what language? I presume you have some existing code you want to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take entire string and take just one part of it, like the last four digits, you can use the SUBSTRING() to store the last four digits.

Use something like this:
$cardNumber = 1234234534564567;
SUBSTR( $cardNumeber , -4 );
it will get only 4567.

I hope helps you!

Answer (score -1):

set new using substr function

```
$newVar = substr($oldVar, -4);
```

and send newVar to database